# Can you embed GtkWidgets in a ClutterStage?

Tags: gtk, clutter

Any example I have seen seems to be embedding a ClutterStage in a GtkWidget.

links:

http://www.openismus.com/documents/clutter_tutorial/1.0/docs/tutorial/html/sec-stage.html

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=4202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can when using the clutter-gtk library - but only on X11 currently.

you can only embed gtk+ widgets inside a ClutterStage that was created by a GtkClutterEmbed widget, by using the GtkClutterActor:

http://docs.clutter-project.org/docs/clutter-gtk/stable/GtkClutterActor.html

this is an example included inside clutter-gtk:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter-gtk/tree/examples/gtk-clutter-test-actor.c

Comment: ok those examples make sense, im not sure how I missed it.  I know mutter manages its windows as actors on a stage.  I was hoping I could use a clutter actor inside a gtk application, but im guessing this is not possible?  it would have to be a gtk widget inside a clutter application ?

Comment: you can add a ClutterActor inside a GtkWidget using GtkClutterEmbed, in clutter-gtk. remember, though, that mutter is not a gtk application, so it shouldn't have any influence on your decisions.